# redux logic - functional component dispatch from mysql populate

Tags: reactjs, redux

okay, so I'm new to react/redux. and I'm struggling with dispatch logic... I think this should register as an event... but I'm confused as to why it is not.

the basic idea is I have a container that displays a list of objects that house a form for that particular entry. I get the data from a server (mysql database) and hydrate the component... but... the console.log('finished loading') runs, with the payload... however - the dispatch does nothing.

I feel like I'm just a little bit off, and this is my first time working with redux... still grasping at straws a bit.

in the jobContainer

```
        const store= useStore();
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
        useEffect(()=>{
            console.log("starting call");
            fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(data=>dispatch({type:"populate",payload:data}))
            .then((data)=>console.log("finished call",data))
            .then(()=>setLoading(false))
        },[]);
```

then I have a jobCardSlice file

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';


export const JobCardSlice = createSlice({
    name:"jobs",
    initialState:[],
    reducers:{
        update: state=>{
            console.log(state);//to be added
            //so this needs to send an async server update
        },
        reset: state=>{
            console.log(state);//to be added
        },
        materialView:state=>{
            console.log(state);//to be added
        },
        complete:state=>{
            console.log(state);//to be added
        },
        populate:(state,payload)=>{
            console.log("populate is up and running!")
            console.log(state,payload);
            state.jobs = payload;
        }

    },
});
export const {update, reset,materialView,complete,populate}=JobCardSlice.actions;

export const selectJobs = (state,action) =>{
     return state.jobs;
}
export default JobCardSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the action is not `populate` but `jobs/populate` (prefixed with the slice name), so that's why the dispatch is not doing anything.

Install the Redux DevTools chrome extension, it's really useful and more so that you are starting to use redux.

Comment: changing that does nothing, it was firing before - with the console log (populate is up and running) so it works up to that point, but it doesn't register the state change.